# ¿Cómo hacer que el bot le de la bienvenida a un miembro al unirse al servidor?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Estoy intentando hacer que mi bot de discord le de la bienvenida desde un canal específico a un nuevo miembro que se una a mi servidor:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
bot = commands.Bot(
    command_prefix=".",
    description="Este es el bot de ayuda",
    intents=intents
)


@bot.event
async def bienvenida(member): # "member" es el miembro que se acaba de unir.

    # Obtenemos el servidor al que el usuario se acaba de unir.
    guild = bot.get_guild(878337838997983233)
    # Obtenemos el canal donde se le dará la bienvenida al nuevo miembro.
    channel = guild.get_channel(878337839589376042)
    # Le damos la bienvenida al nuevo miembro.
    await channel.send(f"Bienvenido a Flex {member.mention}")
```

El problema que tengo es que, dentro de la función `bienvenida()`, no consigo que se ejecute con éxito la línea "`channel = guild.get_channel(...)`". Me resulta extraño ya que justo la línea anterior, esto es "`guild = bot.get_guild(...)`", sí se ejecuta.

No sé a qué se debe esto ni como continuar.

Comment: algún error por consola??

Comment: @Christian no, simplemente no toma la funcion. Es muy raro, sigo sin saber que hacer. Reescribi el codigo varias veces pensando en algun error de sintaxis, pero nada.

Comment: y si haces un `print(channel)` que obtienes??

Answer (score 2):

El decorador `@bot.event` sirve para indicar que la función decorada va a manejar un evento específico. Cuál es el evento a ser manejado por la función viene dado por el nombre de la misma. En tu caso, estás intentando manejar el evento "`bienvenida`".

Tal como puedes ver en la [documentación](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=events#event-reference), no hay ningún evento con dicho nombre y, por tanto, la función no está siendo aplicada sobre ningún evento existente.

El evento que debes redefinir es [`on_member_join()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=events#discord.on_member_join), que es el evento que se llama cada vez que un miembro se une a un servidor (siempre y cuando esta información sea visible por el bot). Una vez le hayas cambiado el nombre a tu función, esta debería funcionar "correctamente".

Ten en cuenta que, con tu código actual, se va a mandar un mensaje al servidor "Flex" cada vez que el bot detecte que un usuario se ha unido a un servidor, aunque este no sea "Flex". Deberías modificar el cuerpo de la función para corregir esto, por ejemplo, comprobando que el servidor al que el usuario se ha unido sea "Flex":

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member : discord.Member):
    if member.guild.id == 878337838997983233:
        channel = member.guild.get_channel(878337839589376042)
        await channel.send(f"Bienvenido a Flex {member.mention}")
```